# When hovering over item showing child and animating other items

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm having 5 circles with inside a picture. Once clicking on the picture, I want to show the details of that picture, but only the details about that 1 picture, not the others. The others should be animated since the detail cadre is pretty big and overlays the other circles. So what should happen? All circles should be animated towards the middle (underneath each other) and the one that has been clicked on should be on top. If this is not possible, I would want them to fade in towards the middle. There's also a button, back to show all circles again.

This is the html I have:

```
<section class="pakketten">
            <header>
                <h1>Pakketten</h1>
            </header>
            <button class="back">back</button>
            <div class="pakket">
                <div class="vis">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <img src="_img/jets.png" width="71" height="107" alt="jets" name="jets">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="invis-wrapper">
                    <div class="invis">
                        <h2>Jets</h2>
                        <p>Een « jet pack », deze jets kun je aansluiten op jouw voertuig. Door de kleine boost spring je als ware in de lucht voor een korte tijd en kun je langs een heleboel obstakels geraken, ook kan het gebruikt worden om coole tricks uit te voeren.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pakket">
                <div class="vis">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <img src="_img/jets.png" width="71" height="107" alt="jets" name="jets">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="invis-wrapper">
                    <div class="invis">
                        <h2>Jets</h2>
                        <p>Een « jet pack », deze jets kun je aansluiten op jouw voertuig. Door de kleine boost spring je als ware in de lucht voor een korte tijd en kun je langs een heleboel obstakels geraken, ook kan het gebruikt worden om coole tricks uit te voeren.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pakket">
                <div class="vis">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <img src="_img/jets.png" width="71" height="107" alt="jets" name="jets">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="invis-wrapper">
                    <div class="invis">
                        <h2>Jets</h2>
                        <p>Een « jet pack », deze jets kun je aansluiten op jouw voertuig. Door de kleine boost spring je als ware in de lucht voor een korte tijd en kun je langs een heleboel obstakels geraken, ook kan het gebruikt worden om coole tricks uit te voeren.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pakket">
                <div class="vis">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <img src="_img/jets.png" width="71" height="107" alt="jets" name="jets">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="invis-wrapper">
                    <div class="invis">
                        <h2>Jets</h2>
                        <p>Een « jet pack », deze jets kun je aansluiten op jouw voertuig. Door de kleine boost spring je als ware in de lucht voor een korte tijd en kun je langs een heleboel obstakels geraken, ook kan het gebruikt worden om coole tricks uit te voeren.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pakket">
                <div class="vis">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <img src="_img/jets.png" width="71" height="107" alt="jets" name="jets">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="invis-wrapper">
                    <div class="invis">
                        <h2>Jets</h2>
                        <p>Een « jet pack », deze jets kun je aansluiten op jouw voertuig. Door de kleine boost spring je als ware in de lucht voor een korte tijd en kun je langs een heleboel obstakels geraken, ook kan het gebruikt worden om coole tricks uit te voeren.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

The class "vis" are the circles that are visible without clicking on them.

The class "invis-wrapper" is the class that should be visible once clicked.

I have tried it using this code:

```
$(".vis").click(function() {
    $(".invis-wrapper").fadeToggle(1000);
});
$(".back").click(function() {
    $(".invis-wrapper").fadeToggle(1000);
});
```

What this does now, is showing all the details, of every circle. Which is not what I wanted.

But I don't seem to find how I can select the class "invis-wrapper" from the circle I click. So what I think I need is to select the parent (class = pakket) and then select that one's child (class = "invis-wrapper"). But I can't seem to find out how to do that.

EDIT: CSS added

```
.pakketten {

    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;

    header {
        width: 462px;
        height: 86px;
        background-image: url(../_img/pakh.png);
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        font-size: 1.8em;

        h1 {
            color: $red;
        }
    }
}

.pakket {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;

    &:last-child {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
}

.circle {
    width: 144px;
    height: 144px;
    background-image: url(../_img/pakcircle.png);

    img {
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-top: 18px;
    }
}

.invis-wrapper {

    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -162px;
    margin-left: -60px;
    display: none;

    h2 {
        font-family: "Prohibition-Lines";
        color: $red;
        margin-top: 180px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    p {
        width: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: "Lora";
        color: $green;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

}

.invis {
    position: absolute;
    width: 266px;
    height: 384px;
    background-image: url(../_img/pakbg.png);
}

.back {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: We lack your CSS, and what you want to do is show `invis-wrapper` when pakket is hovered ? You can do that with CSS `>`

Comment: @CristianD I have added my css. I want to show the invis-wrapper from the one that has been clicked on. Not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you want.

When you click the image (`.vis`), select only [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) of the clicked element.

When you click the back button, only `fadeToggle` on visible elements by using the [visible selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

```
$(".vis").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".invis-wrapper").fadeToggle(1000);
});
$(".back").click(function () {
    $(".invis-wrapper:visible").fadeToggle(1000);
});
```

Comment: This is indeed part of what I want! The back button, doesn't seem to work though. It doesn't make the detail div that is visible back to invisible. Also how can I now animate the rest of them?